# Obtain NSImage from Pixel Array Problems (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, byte, pixel, cgimage

L.E : I've found the issue, now it does'n crashing anymore, but now ( new issue ) it doesn't draw the image as it should.. It is damaged...

I have a pixel array I need to turn into a CGImage and then into a NSImage. I've tried this version of a code used on ios for obtaining aUIImage and I get an error I can not handle: **CGImageCreate: invalid image bits/pixel or bytes/row.
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Any idea, any help will be honestly appreciated! Thank you! I'll let the code here :

```
 func imageFromPixels(image : CGImage, size:NSSize,pixels: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, width: Int, height: Int)-> NSImage {
    let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo:CGBitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)
   let bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image)
    let bitsPerPixel = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(image)
    let bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image)
    var data = pixels
    let providerRef = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(
        NSData(bytes: &data, length: height * width  * sizeof(UInt8))
    )

    let cgim = CGImageCreate(
        width,
        height,
        bitsPerComponent,
        bitsPerPixel,
        bitsPerRow,
        rgbColorSpace,
        bitmapInfo,
        providerRef,
        nil,
        true,
        .RenderingIntentDefault
    )
    return NSImage(CGImage: cgim!, size: size)
}
```

Comment: Please note that this is not a duplicate because I need this to develop on osx, not ios and because I am not using a RGB struct.

Comment: Note that the code in the answer creates a CGImage first, and that should work on both OS X and iOS. You can replace the array of RGB structs with an array of the pixel data.

Comment: I've tried this method, unfortunately it crashes...

Comment: Then update your question and show what you tried, where/how it crashes etc.

Comment: The exact same code you pointed out, only exception was the raw pixel parameter. This is why I needed this question still open...

Comment: Update your question and add your code, the input data, information about the crash etc! Otherwise it might be closed again as "unclear what you are asking" or "too broad" ...

Comment: Thank you very much! I've edited and adapted it. :D

Comment: Most probably it should be `NSData(bytes: data, ...)` without the `&`.

Comment: I've tried that too, no difference :(

Comment: *Hint:* Your length calculation in CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData is wrong.

Comment: @MartinR , modifying the length value does, indeed, affect de amount of distortion in my image. Thank's for the hint, I am now trying to find out how I should calculate it properly. :D

Comment: Please do not deface you own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your new code has more faults than the older one, so some fixes:

```
func imageFromPixels(size: NSSize, pixels: UnsafePointer<UInt8>, width: Int, height: Int)-> NSImage { //No need to pass another CGImage
    let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo:CGBitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)
    let bitsPerComponent = 8 //number of bits in UInt8
    let bitsPerPixel = 4 * bitsPerComponent //ARGB uses 4 components
    let bytesPerRow = bitsPerPixel * width / 8 // bitsPerRow / 8 (in some cases, you need some paddings)
    let providerRef = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(
        NSData(bytes: pixels, length: height * bytesPerRow) //Do not put `&` as pixels is already an `UnsafePointer`
    )

    let cgim = CGImageCreate(
        width,
        height,
        bitsPerComponent,
        bitsPerPixel,
        bytesPerRow, //->not bits
        rgbColorSpace,
        bitmapInfo,
        providerRef,
        nil,
        true,
        .RenderingIntentDefault
    )
    return NSImage(CGImage: cgim!, size: size)
}
```

See comments in the code.