# How to interpret result of MLMultiArray in semantic segmentation through CoreML?

Tags: xcode, coreml, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to implement a semantic segmentation model in my application. I have been able to convert the u2net model to a CoreML model. I am unable to get a workable result from the MLMultiArray output. The specification description is as follows:

```
input {
  name: "input"
  type {
    imageType {
      width: 512
      height: 512
      colorSpace: RGB
    }
  }
}
output {
  name: "x_1"
  type {
    multiArrayType {
      shape: 1
      shape: 3
      shape: 512
      shape: 512
      dataType: FLOAT32
    }
  }
}
```

The model works great when opening it and using the model preview functionality in Xcode. It shows the 2 different labels in 2 colours (there are only 2 classes + 1 background). I want to have the same output in my application, however when I manually process the MLMultiArray output to a CGImage I get different results. I am using the code provided [here](https://github.com/powermobileweb/CoreMLHelpers) like this:

```
let image = output.cgImage(min: -1, max: 1, channel: 0, axes: (1,2,3))
```

This gives me something that looks somewhat usable but it has a lot of gradient within each channel. What I need is an image with simply 1 color value for each label.

I have tried converting the output of the model directly to an image through [this sample code](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/81571#241998). This simply shows 'Inference Failed' in the Xcode model preview. When I try removing the unnecessary extra dimension in the MultiArray output I get this error:

```
"Error reading protobuf spec. validator error: Layer 'x_1' of type 'Convolution' has output rank 3 but expects rank at least 4."
```

What does the model preview in Xcode do what I am not doing? Is there a post processing step I need to take to get usable output?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

Turns out the resulting pixels for each channel represent the possibility of it being the class represented by that channel.

In other words find the maximum pixel value at a certain position. The channel with the highest value is the class pixel.

```
func getLabelsForImage() { 
    ....
    setup model here
    ....
    guard let output = try? model.prediction(input: input) else {
        fatalError("Could not generate model output.")
    }
    let channelCount = 10

    // Ugly, I know. But works:
    let colors = [NSColor.red.usingColorSpace(.sRGB)!, NSColor.blue.usingColorSpace(.sRGB)!, NSColor.green.usingColorSpace(.sRGB)!, NSColor.gray.usingColorSpace(.sRGB)!, NSColor.yellow.usingColorSpace(.sRGB)!, NSColor.purple.usingColorSpace(.sRGB)!, NSColor.cyan.usingColorSpace(.sRGB)!, NSColor.orange.usingColorSpace(.sRGB)!, NSColor.brown.usingColorSpace(.sRGB)!, NSColor.magenta.usingColorSpace(.sRGB)!]
    
    // I don't know my min and max output, -64 and 64 seems to work OK for my data.
    var firstData = output.toRawBytes(min: Float32(-64), max: Float32(64), channel: 0, axes: (0,1,2))!.bytes
    var outputImageData:[UInt8] = []
    for _ in 0..<firstData.count {
        let r:UInt8 = UInt8(colors[0].redComponent * 255)
        let g:UInt8 = UInt8(colors[0].greenComponent * 255)
        let b:UInt8 = UInt8(colors[0].blueComponent * 255)
        let a:UInt8 = UInt8(colors[0].alphaComponent * 255)
        
        outputImageData.append(r)
        outputImageData.append(g)
        outputImageData.append(b)
        outputImageData.append(a)
    }
    
    for i in 1..<channelCount {
        let data = output.toRawBytes(min: Float32(-64), max: Float32(64), channel: i, axes: (0,1,2))!.bytes
        for j in 0..<data.count {
            if data[j] > firstData[j] {
                firstData[j] = data[j]
                let r:UInt8 = UInt8(colors[i].redComponent * 255)
                let g:UInt8 = UInt8(colors[i].greenComponent * 255)
                let b:UInt8 = UInt8(colors[i].blueComponent * 255)
                let a:UInt8 = UInt8(colors[i].alphaComponent * 255)
                
                outputImageData[j*4] = r
                outputImageData[j*4+1] = g
                outputImageData[j*4+2] = b
                outputImageData[j*4+3] = a
            }
        }
    }
    
    let image = imageFromPixels(pixels: outputImageData, width: 512, height: 512)
    image.writeJPG(toURL: labelURL.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("labels.jpg"))
}

// I found this function here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38590323/obtain-nsimage-from-pixel-array-problems-swift
func imageFromPixels(pixels: UnsafePointer<UInt8>, width: Int, height: Int)-> NSImage { //No need to pass another CGImage
    let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo:CGBitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
    let bitsPerComponent = 8 //number of bits in UInt8
    let bitsPerPixel = 4 * bitsPerComponent //ARGB uses 4 components
    let bytesPerRow = bitsPerPixel * width / 8 // bitsPerRow / 8 (in some cases, you need some paddings)
    let providerRef = CGDataProvider(
        data: NSData(bytes: pixels, length: height * bytesPerRow) //Do not put `&` as pixels is already an `UnsafePointer`
    )

    let cgim = CGImage(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
        bitsPerPixel: bitsPerPixel,
        bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, //->not bits
        space: rgbColorSpace,
        bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,
        provider: providerRef!,
        decode: nil,
        shouldInterpolate: true,
        intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent
    )
    return NSImage(cgImage: cgim!, size: NSSize(width: width, height: height))
}
```